# imap headers returned formatted string broken down into values

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that is returned via imap_headers() which has a format like this one:

```
Flags Number) Date Sender Subject (Size)
```

and sample returned string from an array is:

```
A 454)22-Jun-2004 cust.serv@amazon.co.uk Your Amazon.co.uk Order (5284 chars)
1)10-Oct-2010 Gmail Team Get Gmail on your mobile (2457 chars)
5)12-Nov-2010 =?ISO-8859-1?Q?Eric_ For Website (671669 chars)
U 6)17-Nov-2010 no-reply@hostmessage host.net account : boom (2082 chars)
```

I want to decode/parse this string and create an object out from this string.
e.g

```
Flags
Date
Sender
Subject
```

i find it hard parsing this using php string functions because, this string is just separated by a space. Can anybody help me on this? The sender part could also be a name, so we can just treat it as an email add or a website url.

Comment: Only based on a single example it is pretty much impossible to write a regular expression that will solve your problem. You will have to do that yourself. Try it and then post your result and your problem with it so we can help you improve your regular expression.

Comment: yeah. like what I've thought, it's pretty impossible.

Comment: It's not impossible at all. It's just not possible for us to figure out what you need based on what information you provided. If you never heard about regular expressions, it will definitely be quite hard to get a proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned above in the comments, it's pretty much impossible to create a regular expression that will work for you, because you don't provide enough information. However, I will give you an example that will match your line and maybe you can go on from there:

```
preg_match('_([A-Z]+) (\d+)\)(\d+-[A-Za-z]+-\d{4}) (\S+@\S+\.\S+) (.+) \((\d+) chars\)_', $header, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Now it depends on your application if you need to extend this expression to account for other variants of the possible output. You can read up on all the details of what I did there in the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).

Comment: Maybe this helps you even if it's a German page: http://regexp-evaluator.de/evaluator/3f07ca4aeb6f58721dfee93177696a0e/#ergebnis You can fiddle around with the regular expression there and look at what result it yields. Should be pretty much straightforward even if you don't understand the page. ;)

Comment: thanks man. I will try this one. much respect for the effort.

Comment: is it okay for you if I'll post here the variety possible string results?

Comment: I'd rather that you try to figure out what I did there. ;) You will have to learn about the magic of regular expressions at some point anyway. But you can add more examples to your question and if I can find the time I might lend you a hand in modifying the expression.

Comment: okay i'll post some more examples, but i'll try my best to solve this. again, thanks a heap. :)

Comment: Sorry to say so, but with those examples it looks like it's impossible to write a proper regular expression for that. It's easy enough to make those flags optional but when you look at the second example: How to decide where the sender ends and where the subject starts? Impossible. You need to change the output format, if you can.